# What is the meaning of stripping libraries warning in a react native build with Android SDK?

Tags: android, react-native, static-linking

In the end of compilation of an Android SDK app which is based on React Native, I can observe a message which confuses me:

```
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they
are: 

libc++_shared.so, libfb.so, libfbjni.so, libfolly_futures.so,  
libfolly_json.so, libglog.so, libglog_init.so, libhermes-executor
debug.so, libhermes-executor-release.so, libhermes-inspector.so,
libhermes.so, libimagepipeline.so, libjscexecutor.so, 
libjsijniprofiler.so, libjsinspector.so, libnative-filters.so,
libnative-imagetranscoder.so, libreactnativeblob.so,
libreactnativejni.so, libyoga.so.
```

What does this message mean? Does it mean the app compiles with those libs statically linked? Isn't it actually good to support a broader range of devices/environment versions, similar like we have it with Golang builds?